# Preventing \texttt LaTeX tag from letting its content passing over the margin

Tags: latex, hyphenation, texttt

In my report, I'm writing some class names or variable names inside of a paragraph, and I want these names to be rendered in a monospace font.

Example:

```
This is my class name: \texttt{baseAdminConfiguration}.
```

Sometimes when the single word inside of the \texttt tag is rendered at the end of a line, the word does not go to the next line, and there is no break in it neither: the end of the word passes over the margin.

How should I handle such a case?

Cheers.

Answer (score 45, accepted):

This hasn’t got much to do with `\texttt`. The word is simply too long, and LaTeX doesn’t know how to hyphenate it. You can tell it how to do this manually, by declaring hyphenation rules:

```
\hyphenation{base-Admin-Configuration}
```

The `\hyphenation` command may take arbitrarily many words, separated by whitespace.

Alternatively, if this doesn’t the trick, you can introduce manual hypenation hints in the text:

```
This is a long text that uses the word \texttt{base\-Admin\-Configuration) …
```

Only the actual hyphenation will be displayed – unused so-called discretionary hyphens (`\-`) will not be displayed so you can freely sprinkle your text with them, if necessary.

[[Read more about hyphenation in LaTeX](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Formatting#Hyphenation)]

To prevent LaTeX from overflowing lines *in principle*, the whole paragraph can be wrapped in a `sloppypar` environment (thanks to Will for pointing this out in the comments):

```
\begin{sloppypar}
  Some text …
\end{sloppypar}
```

This manipulates the parameters of the line-breaking algorithm (in particular, `\tolerance`). The downside: this can lead to very ugly spacing. Alternatively, `\tolerance` and other internal parameters can be manipulated directly – the TeX FAQ [shows how](http://www.tex.ac.uk/cgi-bin/texfaq2html?label=overfull).

Comment: Quick question: Is it possible to get LaTeX to break the line early instead of overrunning the margin?

Comment: @Anon: well, you can always *force* a line break using `\\` or `\newline`. Or you might put the text in a `flushleft` environment – it won’t be justified then. But in general, no, not that I’m aware of. Perhaps it’s possible to tweak the internal parameters of the line-break algorithm. I don’t know.

Comment: The closest you can get is wrap the paragraph with `\begin{sloppypar}...\end{sloppypar}` to allow poorer linebreaks. (Or write `\sloppy` to activate it globally.)

Comment: @Will: oh yes I forgot about `sloppypar`. `\sloppy`, on the other hand, is deprecated and shouldn’t be used.

Comment: Erm, news to me about \sloppy. Any reference for that?

Comment: @Will: The source is l2tabu (section 1.8) from de.comp.text.tex which claims to echo a consensus among TeXperts. http://tug.ctan.org/tex-archive/info/l2tabu. But I won’t argue with the guy whose name appears in about every second result to LaTeX-related searches.

Comment: Ah, thanks! l2tabu warns against `\sloppy` in general and gives lots of better alternatives. But that isn't to say it's deprecated as such, just to be used with care.

Comment: Thank you all for your great answers! Finally in my case I used manual hyphenation, as my class mane is only written once or twice in my report. I'm keeping in mind the \hyphenation and \sloppypar tags.

Comment: And how can I tell LaTeX not to use `-` in hyphenation? I have Perl module name, e.g. `XXX::YYY::ZZZ` and I want to break this name in that way: `XXX::-YYY::-ZZZ` but I don't want hyphen.

Comment: @jesper Never tried this but perhaps you can solve this by setting `\hyphenchar` to whitespace: ``\hyphenchar\font=`\ ``.

Answer (score 4):

The solution is quite simple: use the url package and replace the texttt command with the path command.

I found out that here
https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/299/how-to-get-long-texttt-sections-to-break
in the post of Will Robertson.

Cheers

Comment: This does not help, when we have long complex class names. It breaks pathes at the file separator only. And it also removes whitespaces, e.g. in a method’s parameter declaration.